# create program launch icon (or shortcut) on windows 8 desktop

Tags: windows-8, shortcuts, launcher, application-launch

I noticed that if you install applications like Visual Studio, its launch icon doesn't appear on the desktop. On the other hand, for apps like Google Chrome browser, the launch icon appears on the desktop right after its installation completes.

How to create a desktop shortcut to your favorite app, say notepad or Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4):

This is really easy.

1. Go to start screen. Press the windows key. Find application you are looking for. Say Notepad. Just type "note"; windows will search and list the application for you. 
   [image]
2. Right click on Notepad to get the command bar at the bottom.
   [image]
3. Click on Open File Location command. This will take you to the executable path or shortcut location (Windows Explorer). Select, right-click and from the context menu copy this.
   [image]
4. Browse to the Desktop Location. Click the shortcut on the right-panel on the top saying "Desktop".
5. Right-click and Paste.
   [image]
   Your shortcut is ready.

Answer (score 1):

Even faster: once you are viewing your app in Windows Explorer just right click it and select Create Shortcut. Windows will tell you it can't create a shortcut where you are and ask if you'd like to place it on your Desktop instead.